# How to make a Text content disappear after some time in JavaFX?

Tags: text, javafx, javafx-2, blink

```
b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connect = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                                + "user=root&password=virus");
                statement = connect.createStatement();

                preparedStatement = connect
                        .prepareStatement("select * from mark where clsnum = " + txt1.getText() + "");
                rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    delete();
                } else {
                    msg.setText("Student Not Found...!");
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DeleteMark.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my code to display a message if the query not worked(I mean if no row is returned to ResultSet rs). msg is an object of Text and its declaration and other details are -

```
Text msg = new Text();
msg.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.THIN, 18));
msg.setFill(Color.RED);
```

I want to make the Text disappear after sometime, like 3 or 4 seconds. Is it possible to do it in JavaFX (with the help of timer or something else you know) ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Please don't post irrelevant code such as your database query in your question.  UI work has nothing to do with database work and you should keep both your question code and your implementation code separate for such things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Timelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and/or [Transitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html).

This answer is for a previous iteration of the question.

**Sample solution code**

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BlinkingAndFading extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label = new Label("Blinking");
        label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-padding: 10px;");

        Timeline blinker = createBlinker(label);
        blinker.setOnFinished(event -> label.setText("Fading"));
        FadeTransition fader = createFader(label);

        SequentialTransition blinkThenFade = new SequentialTransition(
                label,
                blinker,
                fader
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 100, 50));
        stage.show();

        blinkThenFade.play();
    }

    private Timeline createBlinker(Node node) {
        Timeline blink = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(0),
                        new KeyValue(
                                node.opacityProperty(), 
                                1, 
                                Interpolator.DISCRETE
                        )
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(0.5),
                        new KeyValue(
                                node.opacityProperty(), 
                                0, 
                                Interpolator.DISCRETE
                        )
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(1),
                        new KeyValue(
                                node.opacityProperty(), 
                                1, 
                                Interpolator.DISCRETE
                        )
                )
        );
        blink.setCycleCount(3);

        return blink;
    }

    private FadeTransition createFader(Node node) {
        FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(2), node);
        fade.setFromValue(1);
        fade.setToValue(0);

        return fade;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Answers to additional questions**

> lambda expression not expected here lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

You should use Java 8 and not set `-source 1.7`.  If you wish to stick with Java 7 (which I don't advise for JavaFX work), you can replace the Lambda:

```
blinker.setOnFinished(event -> label.setText("Fading"));
```

with:

```
blinker.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Fading");
    }
});
```

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Again, you should use Java 8.  But if you wish to use Java 7, replace:

```
stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 100, 50));
```

with:

```
StackPane layout = new StackPane();
layout.getChildren().add(label);
stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 100, 50));
```

**Further recommendations**

Good call on not having the text both blink and fade.  Blinking text makes for pretty distracting UI, but just fading is fine.

I don't think I'd recommend fading an error message, at least until the user clicks on it or something like that.  What if the user didn't see the error message before it faded away?

Comment: There are 2 error - 1.  blinker.setOnFinished(event -> label.setText("Fading"));  (Reason - lambda expression not expected here

lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions))   2.  stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 100, 50)); ( Reason - constructor StackPane in class StackPane cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: Label
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length).  Can you correct that 2. It will be very helpful.

Comment: One more help. I edited my question. Will you please edit your answer according to it ?

Comment: I removed blinking. You just say me how to increase the time before fading.

Comment: I found that too. Thanks for your help.